# Announcement: We have our 5,000th question

Tags: discussion

The Quaerometer ticked over to 5,000 on [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17030/32). I urge everyone to click over and shake Theo warmly by the virtual hand ...

... and then pat [genderneutral]self soundly on the back!

Answer (score 1):

Celebrations!

I actually noticed the counter at 4998, but when I answered the question I never realized it was #5000!

Comment: Upvoted so "Community" doesn't bump it anymore.